# What tools can I use to make an emojie service like windows on Linux?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, python, java, programming

On windows 10, one of the more recent updates, you can use the shortcut windows key + . to open up a small window next to the focussed textbox and you can use that to quickly enter in emojies.

What I would like to know is what is the best tool to use to make something like this on ubuntu? Could I use Java? And what tools would I possibly need?

And lastly do you have any tips for me before I start working on this? Anything I might need to know?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an utility to quickly search for emojis and enter into a text editor/message window, then you can use the `characters` utility preloaded in Ubuntu.

> 1. Open the `Application menu` by pressing the `super key` (windows key
>    on keyboard)
> 2. Type `characters` in the search field and open the utility
> 3. Now just click on any character/emoji of your choice and copy and
>    paste into your editor/message window.

If you are planning to create an application of your own, then you will need to use `C lanuguage` and `GTK+ cross platform` to write a GUI application of your own for Ubuntu.

**Tutorial for building apps for Ubuntu:**

> https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. So I can only make it with C? Can I not use a high level programming langauge?

Comment: Well apps on Ubuntu can be written in variety of languages. I think `C` and `Python` are most popular.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1162/emoji-selector/

Install the gnome extension by clicking on and then you can select a emoji, when you select the emoji on the panel there it will copy it to the clipboard and then you just do <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and it's done. If you hate it then uninstall using clicking off it.

The gnome extension is using java script and I don't think javascript is C.

Comment: Thank you for this. The functionality is close to being what I want, if only clicking on the emojie would paste it immediately if a text box is on focus. But this is great. Thank you.